# Find A-3I inverse if you have characteristic polynomial and matrix S,D such that $SDS^T=A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, diagonalization

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
  3&1 &1 \\
  1&3& 1\\
    1&1&3 
$
\end{bmatrix}$$
First part  of problem was to find matrix $S$ such that $SDS^T=A$. Very easy find characteristic polynomial $k_A(\lambda)=-\lambda^3+9\lambda^2-24\lambda+20$.

$k_A(\lambda)=0$ iff $\lambda=5, \lambda=2$ and one more $\lambda=2$, and than find eig. vectors...

Second part of problem is to find inverse of A-3I, but you must use part a) in your solution.

My solution:
First idea was to use HC theorem:
$-A^3+9A^2-24A+20I=0$ and rewrite this polinomial as a sums of $(A-3I)$ (Taylor series at point 3)
$$2I+3(A-3I)-(A-3I)^3=0$$

 $T=A-3I$
$$T^3-3T-2I=0$$
$$T^3-3T=2I$$
$$T(T^2-3I)=2I$$
$$T(\frac{T^2-3I}{2})=I$$
By definition of inverse all inside brackets is inverse of $T=A-3I$.

---

My question is there any more "linear algebra" approach in this problem.

Comment: Linear Algebra is allowed to use ordinary algebra. In fact, when the result can be obtained just using $A$ as an unknown, that reveals the essential 
"why" of the problem, so looking further misses the point that it just depends on elementary algebra. The linear algebra part was getting the characteristic polynomial. After that, elementary algebra (as you showed) suffices to finish the rest.